# boton de finalizar orden no funciona en woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

el boton de finalizar orden no hace nada. active y desactive plugins, temas, mire la consola para ver si habia problemas de js y nada. el debug no me tira errores excepto este que ya desactive el plugin

[27-May-2022 18:11:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rut_not_required in /home/mobie/public_html/www1/wp-content/plugins/rut-chileno-con-validacion/includes/class-wc-chilean-bundle-logic.php on line 18

la web es https://mobie.cl

este es el estado de woocomerce

`

#### WordPress Environment

```
WordPress address (URL): https://mobie.cl/www1
Site address (URL): https://mobie.cl/www1
WC Version: 6.5.1
REST API Version: ✔ 6.5.1
WC Blocks Version: ✔ 7.4.3
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.4.0
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 6.0
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 512 MB
WP Debug Mode: ✔
WP Cron: ✔
Language: es_ES
External object cache: –
```

#### Server Environment

```
Server Info: LiteSpeed
PHP Version: 7.4.24
PHP Post Max Size: 128 MB
PHP Time Limit: 600
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.71.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1d

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.7.36
Max Upload Size: 128 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔
```

#### Database

```
C Database Version: 6.5.1
WC Database Prefix: wpvh_
Tamaño total de la base de datos: 117.88MB
Tamaño de los datos de la base de datos: 84.18MB
Tamaño del índice de la base de datos: 33.70MB
wpvh_woocommerce_sessions: Datos: 0.14MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_api_keys: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_order_items: Datos: 0.05MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Datos: 0.14MB + Índice: 0.17MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_tax_rates: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_woocommerce_log: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_actionscheduler_actions: Datos: 27.06MB + Índice: 15.19MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_actionscheduler_claims: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_actionscheduler_groups: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_actionscheduler_logs: Datos: 6.52MB + Índice: 5.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_awb_critical_css: Datos: 1.52MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_bv_activities_store: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_bv_fw_requests: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_bv_ip_store: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_bv_lp_requests: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_chaty_contact_form_leads: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_commentmeta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_comments: Datos: 0.19MB + Índice: 0.09MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_duplicator_pro_entities: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_duplicator_pro_packages: Datos: 0.11MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_ewwwio_images: Datos: 2.52MB + Índice: 2.81MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_ewwwio_queue: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_fusion_forms: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_fusion_form_entries: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_fusion_form_fields: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_fusion_form_submissions: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_gla_budget_recommendations: Datos: 0.22MB + Índice: 0.14MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_gla_merchant_issues: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_gla_shipping_rates: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_gla_shipping_times: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_imagify_files: Datos: 2.52MB + Índice: 2.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_imagify_folders: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_layerslider: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_layerslider_revisions: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_links: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_litespeed_img_optm: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_custom_fields: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_dynamic_segment_filters: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_feature_flags: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_forms: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_log: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_mapping_to_external_entities: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletters: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_links: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_option: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_option_fields: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_posts: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_segment: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_newsletter_templates: Datos: 2.52MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_scheduled_tasks: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_scheduled_task_subscribers: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_segments: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_sending_queues: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_settings: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_bounces: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_clicks: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_forms: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_newsletters: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_opens: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.08MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_unsubscribes: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_statistics_woocommerce_purchases: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_stats_notifications: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_subscribers: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.13MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_subscriber_custom_field: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_subscriber_ips: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_subscriber_segment: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_user_agents: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mailpoet_user_flags: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mclean_refs: Datos: 0.05MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_mclean_scan: Datos: 0.05MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_options: Datos: 7.41MB + Índice: 0.22MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_postmeta: Datos: 4.52MB + Índice: 3.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_posts: Datos: 8.41MB + Índice: 0.22MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_css: Datos: 0.14MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_css_bkp: Datos: 0.13MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_layer_animations: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_layer_animations_bkp: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_navigations: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_navigations_bkp: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_sliders: Datos: 0.14MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_sliders_bkp: Datos: 0.05MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_slides: Datos: 1.27MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_slides_bkp: Datos: 0.13MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_static_slides: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_revslider_static_slides_bkp: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_termmeta: Datos: 0.06MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_terms: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_term_relationships: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_term_taxonomy: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_usermeta: Datos: 0.17MB + Índice: 0.16MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_users: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_admin_notes: Datos: 0.06MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_admin_note_actions: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_category_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_customer_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_download_log: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_order_coupon_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_order_product_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_order_stats: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_order_tax_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_product_attributes_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_product_download_directories: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_product_meta_lookup: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.09MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_rate_limits: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_reserved_stock: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_tax_rate_classes: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wc_webhooks: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfblockediplog: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfblocks7: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfconfig: Datos: 3.52MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfcrawlers: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wffilechanges: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wffilemods: Datos: 4.52MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfhits: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfhoover: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfissues: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfknownfilelist: Datos: 2.52MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wflivetraffichuman: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wflocs: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wflogins: Datos: 0.38MB + Índice: 0.14MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfls_2fa_secrets: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfls_settings: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfnotifications: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfpendingissues: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.06MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfreversecache: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfsnipcache: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wfstatus: Datos: 0.14MB + Índice: 0.09MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wftrafficrates: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wpforms_tasks_meta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wpmailsmtp_debug_events: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wpmailsmtp_tasks_meta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wt_iew_action_history: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wt_iew_cron: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wt_iew_ftp: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_wt_iew_mapping_template: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_indexable: Datos: 1.28MB + Índice: 0.33MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_indexable_hierarchy: Datos: 0.05MB + Índice: 0.05MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_migrations: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_primary_term: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_prominent_words: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_seo_links: Datos: 0.08MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
wpvh_yoast_seo_meta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpmdb_alter_statements: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.00MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_actionscheduler_actions: Datos: 1.52MB + Índice: 0.69MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_actionscheduler_claims: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_actionscheduler_groups: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_actionscheduler_logs: Datos: 1.52MB + Índice: 0.34MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_commentmeta: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.03MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_comments: Datos: 0.13MB + Índice: 0.09MB + Motor InnoDB
_mig_wpvh_duplicator_packages: Datos: 0.02MB + Índice: 0.02MB + Motor InnoDB

### Post Type Counts ###

amn_wpforms-lite: 1
attachment: 510
custom_css: 1
customize_changeset: 1
cwginstocknotifier: 41
elementor_library: 1
flamingo_contact: 20
fusion_element: 17
fusion_form: 2
fusion_icons: 3
fusion_tb_layout: 3
fusion_tb_section: 6
fusion_template: 1
layout: 1
mailpoet_page: 1
nav_menu_item: 6
oembed_cache: 1
page: 13
popup: 4
popup_theme: 9
post: 3
product: 49
revision: 1
seedprod: 1
shop_coupon: 3
shop_order: 177
slide: 2
wp_global_styles: 2
wpcf7_contact_form: 2
wpforms: 1
```

#### Security

```
Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔
```

#### Active Plugins (24)

```
Back In Stock Notifier for WooCommerce | WooCommerce Waitlist Pro: por codewoogeek – 2.7
WordPress Backup & Security Plugin - BlogVault: por Backup by BlogVault – 4.78
Chaty: por Premio – 2.9.2
Contact Form 7: por Takayuki Miyoshi – 5.5.6.1
Easy Theme and Plugin Upgrades: por Chris Jean – 2.0.2
Avada Builder: por ThemeFusion – 3.5
Avada Core: por ThemeFusion – 5.5
Google Listings and Ads: por WooCommerce – 1.13.2
Health Check & Troubleshooting: por La comunidad de WordPress.org – 1.4.5
Imagify: por WP Media – 1.10
Facebook for WordPress: por Facebook – 3.0.6
Slider Revolution: por ThemePunch – 6.4.11
WooCommerce - Muestra solo los precios más bajos en productos variables: por Fernando Tellado – 0.9.31
SVG Support: por Benbodhi – 2.4.2
Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce: por ThemeHigh – 1.6.1
Premmerce Permalink Manager for WooCommerce: por premmerce – 2.3.5
WPSPA Spanish Enhacements for WooCommerce: por Closemarketing – 2.1
Transbank Webpay Plus: por Transbank – 2.4.1
WooCommerce: por Automattic – 6.5.1
Yoast SEO: por Equipo Yoast – 18.9
WP Mail SMTP: por WPForms – 3.4.0
WP Rocket | Remove All .htacces Rules: por WP Rocket Support Team –
WP Rocket: por WP Media – 3.8.8
Yoast SEO: WooCommerce: por Team Yoast – 14.1
```

#### Inactive Plugins (4)

```
CMP - Coming Soon & Maintenance Plugin: por NiteoThemes – 4.1.2
MailPoet 3 (New): por MailPoet – 3.89.3
MWB HubSpot for WooCommerce: por MakeWebBetter – 1.3.0
Rut Chileno con validación para WooCommerce: por AndresReyesDev – 1.1.0
```

#### Dropin Plugins (1)

```
advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php
```

#### Must Use Plugins (1)

```
Health Check Troubleshooting Mode: por  – 1.7.2
```

#### Settings

```
API Enabled: –
Force SSL: –
Currency: CLP ($)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: .
Decimal Separator: ,
Number of Decimals: 0
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: –
Enforce Approved Product Download Directories: –
```

#### WC Pages

```
Base de la tienda: #286 - /tienda/
Carrito: #2238 - /cart/
Finalizar compra: #34 - /checkout/
Mi cuenta: #35 - /my-account/
Términos y condiciones: #2715 - /terminos-y-condiciones/
```

#### Theme

```
Name: Avada
Version: 7.5
Author URL: https://themeforest.net/user/ThemeFusion
Child Theme: ❌ – Si estás modificando WooCommerce en un tema padre que no has creado personalmente
te recomendamos utilizar un tema hijo. Ver: Cómo crear un tema hijo

WooCommerce Support: ✔
```

#### Templates

```
Overrides: Avada/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
Avada/woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php
Avada/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php
Avada/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php
Avada/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php
Avada/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
Avada/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php
Avada/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php
Avada/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php
```

#### Action Scheduler

```
Completo: 37.634
Oldest: 2022-05-26 02:45:01 +0000
Newest: 2022-05-28 17:49:38 +0000

Fallida: 1
Oldest: 2022-02-21 19:50:05 +0000
Newest: 2022-02-21 19:50:05 +0000

Pendiente: 7
Oldest: 2022-05-28 17:54:38 +0000
Newest: 2022-05-28 18:50:01 +0000
```

#### Status report information

Generated at: 2022-05-28 13:50:49 -04:00
`

Comment: Va aser dificil que podamos ayudarte a menos que nos de por comprarte algo. El boton Finalizar Compra a mi si me funciona, no se si te referias a ese.

Comment: Toda la información que muestras no sirve de nada, esto es para solucionar problemas de código, en tu caso lo mejor es que hables con soporte  y expongas tu casi, si no tienes un código de error no podemos ayudarte, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.